# Chart.js chart not showing

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I've been having trouble with displayed a 4th chart.js bar chart on my site. The other 3 are displaying just fine but the fourth will not appear even though the code is pretty much copied and pasted from the other charts.

Here is the html with the canvas tags.

```
    <!-- Graphs -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <canvas id="priceByYear"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <canvas id="priceByMileage"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <canvas id="priceByEngine"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <canvas id="priceByFuel"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the script code for one of the working charts and the one that is not working with a print_r() output of the data that I am trying to use.

Array ( [1] => Array ( [fuel] => Diesel [average price] => 11350 ) [0] => Array ( [fuel] => Petrol [average price] => 11350 ) )

Thanks for reading!

```
<!-- Chart Scripts -->
<script>
    let priceByYear = document.getElementById('priceByYear');

    let priceByYearChart = new Chart(priceByYear, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: <?php
                    echo "[";
                    foreach ($averagePricesArray as $p) {
                        echo "{$p['year']},";
                    }
                    echo "]";
                    ?>,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Average price by year',
                data: <?php
                        echo "[";
                        foreach ($averagePricesArray as $p) {
                            echo "{$p['average price']},";
                        }
                        echo "]";
                        ?>,
                backgroundColor: '#01487C',
                borderWidth: 2,
                hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                hoverBorderColor: 'whitesmoke',
            }]
        },
        options: {}
    });

let priceByFuel = document.getElementById('priceByFuel');

    let priceByFuelChart = new Chart(priceByFuel, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: <?php
                    echo "[";
                    foreach ($pricesByFuelArray as $p) {
                        echo "{$p['fuel']},";
                    }
                    echo "]";
                    ?>,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Average price by fuel',
                data: <?php
                        echo "[";
                        foreach ($pricesByFuelArray as $p) {
                            echo "{$p['average price']},";
                        }
                        echo "]";
                        ?>,
                backgroundColor: '#008EC8',
                borderWidth: 2,
                hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                hoverBorderColor: 'whitesmoke',
            }]
        },
        options: {}
    });


</script>
```

Comment: i think problem is in previous $pricesByFuelArray code. Because your above code looks ok...